# Foundation section - all tabs stacked on top of each other, overlapping

Tags: css, tabs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to do a tab group using Foundation 4. The tab buttons are all rendered overlapping each other (FF and Chrome). I've double checked the markup but can't see what I'm doing wrong..

```
 <div data-section class="section-container auto">
          <section class="section">
            <p data-section-title class="title"><a href="#panel1">First Tab</a></p>
            <div data-section-content class="content">
              <p>Content..</p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section class="section">
            <p data-section-title class="title"><a href="#panel2">Second Tab</a></p>
            <div data-section-content class="content">
              <p>Content..</p>
            </div>
          </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh Forgot to include

```
<script src="/js/foundation/foundation.section.js" />
```